# How can a waterline adapter get access to attributes defined in the model?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am building a Sails/WaterLine adaptor for RestLike datasource. In order to return instances to WaterLine I need to transform the result to handle things like dates and null. To do this I need access to the attribute definitions on the model. But I can't figure out how to get access to them.

[sails-rest](https://github.com/zohararad/sails-rest/blob/master/SailsRest.js) appears to somehow store a `definition` object on the connection and then uses it later to format results. This is pretty much what I need, but I do not see how this `definition` object is derived in the first place.

How can a waterline adapter get access to attributes defined in the model?

Answer (score 1):

found it!

The registerConnection method, gets the `collections` argument

That object contains all the models and their definitions. Store it on the connection so you can reference it later in the other adapter methods.

```
registerConnection: function(connection, collections, cb) {
  if(!connection.identity) return cb(new Error('Connection is missing an identity.'));
  if(connections[connection.identity]) return cb(new Error('Connection is already registered.'));

  // Add in logic here to initialize connection
  // e.g. connections[connection.identity] = new Database(connection, collections);

    var dbConnection = '... create connection here ...'

  connections[connection.identity] = {
      dbConnection : dbConnection,
      collections : collections  //  <-- store collection
  }

  cb();
}
```

...later in the other functions where you need the model definition

```
create: function (connection, collection, values, cb){

    // database connection
    var dbConnection = connections[connection].dbConnection;

    // model definition
    var definition = connections[connection].collections[collection].definition

    // do the rest of the stuff
}
```